# Phalcon PHQL GROUP BY error

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, group-by, phalcon

When adding `GROUP BY` to my query, Phalcon is giving me an error - Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception: Syntax error, unexpected token GROUP, near to ' BY...

Here's my code;

```
$phql = "
    SELECT $dist $ads_model.id AS id, $ads_model.title AS title, $ads_model.description AS description, $ads_model.country AS country, $ads_model.city AS city, $ads_model.latitude AS latitude, $ads_model.longitude AS longitude, $image_model.file AS image
    FROM $ads_model
    LEFT JOIN $image_model ON $image_model.ad_id = $ads_model.id
    WHERE $where
    GROUP BY $ads_model.id
    $order
    ";
    $ads = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($phql);
```

Here's the query being generated;

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Manager->executeQuery(\n SELECT (3959 * acos( cos( radians( xxxx ) ) * cos( radians( \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.latitude ) ) * cos( radians( \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.longitude ) - radians( xxxx ) ) + sin( radians( xxxx ) ) * sin( radians( \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance, 
\Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.id AS id, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.title AS title, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.description AS description, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.country AS country, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.city AS city, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.latitude AS latitude, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.longitude AS longitude, \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsImages.file AS image\n 
FROM \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds\n 
LEFT JOIN \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsImages ON \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsImages.ad_id = \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.id\n 
WHERE \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.status = 'active' Having distance <= 100\n 
GROUP BY \Baseapp\Models\ClassifiedsAds.id\n 
ORDER BY distance ASC\n )
```

Running a simplified version of the query in MySQL works as expected. Why is Phalcon screwing up on the `GROUP BY` clause? The query runs if `GROUP BY` is left out. How do I get it to work in PHQL?

Also as a completely related question: I am using PHQL for this as Phalcon's pagination doesn't seem to work with raw MySQL. Is there a way to get Phalcon pagination to work with raw (with out making a custom pagination)?

Comment: What is the `$dist` in your select? `SELECT $dist $ads_model.id AS id`

Comment: @Timothy you can see what `$dist` produces if you look at the generated query, but it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: I see you are using `having` before `group by`. `group by` should come before `having`

Comment: @Timothy thanks that was the problem. I had tagged the `HAVING` on to the end of the `WHERE`. I've moved it to after the `GROUP BY` now and all's ok. I could give you credit if you added it as an answer!

Comment: Yes, do that, then ping us, so we can sprinkle points for a keen eye

Comment: I added the answer, now sprinkle me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in the order of your clauses.

You must declare the `HAVING` clause after your `GROUP BY`.

> ```
> [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
>   [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
> [HAVING where_condition]
> [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
>   [ASC | DESC], ...]
> ```

Refer to the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) for a complete example.

Comment: Even if this does not resolve the problem, +1 for pointing out that `HAVING` should be used between `GROUP BY` and `ORDER`

Comment: It turns out that `Phalcon\Pagination` doesn't seem to work with PHQL so I re did it with query builder, but now when I add the paginator, it seems to break the query when it ads `SELECT COUNT() AS rowcount` to the query. So I still haven't actually got any where, but thanks for pointing out the error of my ways.

Comment: Could you update your question with the code from the query builder?

Comment: Or better yet, create a new question. As your new question doesn't really reflect the original title.

Comment: @Timothy As I think you found, I added a new question. Also you have been sprinkled with fairy dust for answering this question. I hope the fairy dust is to your liking and doesn't sting when it gets into your eyes! ;)